# css style is not applied before i manually interact with the dev tools and trigger a refresh

Tags: css, cordova, android-webview, velocity.js

I'm developing an app with cordova, webview is chromeview 33, device nexus 4.

I'm using a simple backdrop that should change it's opacity to 0.5 when a btn is clicked.

The transition is made with velocity.js, i'm using velocity for other transitions as well and they all work fine.

My background transition however doesn't work on this device/webview, the opacity stays 0 (i think, because i cant see it) while the remote dev tools show a changing value up to 0.5 (correct target value), the effect is only visible after i move my mouse around in chrome dev tools, every mouseover over any element triggers a repaint or something like that where the correct style of 0.5 is applied.

**tl;dr** chrome dev tools **show the correct value as inline style property on the element** but do not *really apply* it until i somehow *trigger a repaint* by **moving my mouse** around in chrome dev tools

this only happens on **chromeview 33 / nexus 4** and *not only when dev tools are opened*

Answer (score 0):

Webkit is riddled with this kind of bugs, you'll have to force reflow by querying a style property of that element that forces layout, e.g. width/height.